# Understanding the reasoning behind Tobit composite likelihood

Tags: likelihood, censoring, tobit-regression, interval-censoring

The [Tobit model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model) defines a likelihood for what amounts to a censored normal distribution - i.e. the tails are clipped - which is meant to be applied to data that has undergone censoring and thus has an expected large probability mass at the censoring points.

Assume that there is both left and right censoring at points $L$ and $U$, that the linear score of a given observation is $x$, the observed value $y$, and the parameter $\sigma$ is fixed at $\sigma:=1$.

Then the likelihood for Tobit model is a mixture of:

- Probability that a draw of the random distribution $N(x)$ would be lower than $L$ for observations that are left censored ($y = L$), given by $P(N(x) < L) = 1 - \Phi(x - L)$.
- Probability that a draw of the random distribution $N(x, \sigma)$ would be higher than $U$ for observations that are right censored ($y = U$), given by $P(N(x) > U) = \Phi(x - U)$.
- Probability density from the normal distribution for observations that are not censored ($L < y < U$), given by $\phi(y - x)$.

(where $\phi$ is the PDF of the standard normal distribution and $\Phi$ its CDF)

If my intuition serves me right, the logic for this composition is as follows: in a censored normal distribution, the probability mass for the censoring points is equivalent to the sum of the probability density function between the tail and infinity, which is equivalent to the cumulative distribution function.

**But here's where I'm confused:** if this argument were to hold, then it should **also** apply in the inverse situation.

Suppose now that censoring is **reversed**: points that are within $L < y < U$ are censored, while points outside of this interval are fully observed.

If one were to follow the same logic, then the likelihood for a point falling in the censored interval should be defined as:
$$
P(L < N(x) < U) = \Phi(U - x) - \Phi(L - x)
$$

Now imagine two scenarios:

- An uncensored normal distribution.
- A distribution with censoring in an interval near zero $L < 0 < U$.

As $L$ and $U$ become closer to each other, the two distributions would converge, and thus their likelihoods should also converge.

Yet, if we imagine that $L = -U$, we have:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \Phi(\epsilon - x) - \Phi(-\epsilon - x) = 0
$$

Which is clearly different from the uncensored case were $y=0$: $\phi(-x)$

So for an observation $y=0$ and $|y| \approx 0$, the two distributions would give very different likelihoods if the Tobit model logic were to be followed.

How come this logic works one way (tails are censored) but not the other (middle interval is censored)? What am I not understanding here?